# Cannot get current node tree with treesitter in Lua in nvim

Tags: neovim, lua, plugin-treesitter

I am trying to get the AST tree to find the node I want. Based on the [doc](https://neovim.io/doc/user/treesitter.html#tsparser:parse()), I should be able to get the tree like this:

```lua
    local parser = vim.treesitter.get_parser(0, vim.o.filetype)
    print('check root', vim.inspect(parser):parse())
```

But it gives me an error on the second line. What have I done wrong?

**Update**

The error message is here:

```
E5108: Error executing lua .../paqs/start/commented.nvim/lua/commented/middlewares.lua:5:
attempt to call method 'parse' (a nil value)
```

Comment: I have added it back in now. sorry for missing that.